# Get page numbers to the outer side in twoside mode

Tags: double-sided

I´d like to use the `twoside` mode for my print but unfortunately the page numbers are on the right side on left pages and vice versa. I´d like to see the page numbers on the `outer side` of each page.

Since I´m not using any `fancy` packages so far I´d like to know which options I have to set to get this.

```
\documentclass[a4paper, 12pt, parskip=full-, listof=totoc, bibliography=totoc, headsepline, twoside]{scrartcl}

\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\usepackage[automark, plainheadsepline]{scrlayer-scrpage}
\pagestyle{scrheadings}
\clearscrheadfoot
\ihead{\headmark}
\ofoot{\pagemark}
\newpairofpagestyles[scrheadings]{plain-custom}{\clearscrheadfoot\ofoot{\pagemark}}

\begin{document}

\newpage

\section{Introduction}

\lipsum[1-20]

\end{document}
```

[image: Inner page numbers]

Comment: The code you've posted doesn't generate the issue of "the page numbers are on the right side on left pages and vice versa". Instead, on recto (i.e., odd-numbered) pages, the page numbers are on the right, and vice versa for verso (i.e., even-numbered) pages.

Comment: @Mico sorry for my bad

I´ve updated a working code sample

Comment: @The 2-page screenshot is maybe a bit misleading, or at least confusing. If you were to print the document two-sided (#2 behind #1, #4 behind #3, etc), you'd notice that the page numbers are always on the outside, exactly as desired.

Comment: May it be that i´ve mixed up the desired order? Should the fist page always start as a right page?
In this case i´m still wonderin why the larger side-border is on the outer and not at the inner side.

Comment: The screenshot you posted doesn't actually show the pages in the way they'd appear if you opened a book that's been printed two-sided. In a book, when you're looking at facing pages, the (near-universal) convention is that even-numbered pages (aka "verso") should be on the left and odd-numbered pages (aka "recto") should be on the right. Another typographic convention is for the "outer" margins (those facing outward, away from the book's spine) should be larger than the "inner" margins. Again, that's exactly what you're getting with your current setup.